# NullPointerException after orientation change

Tags: java, android, orientation, picasso

With the following code, i get an error when i rotate the device.

```
Picasso.with(container.getContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + mMovie.getPosterPath()).error(R.drawable.noimagefound).into((ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_poster));
```

This only happens when i rotate the screen. If i have a break point and i debug the code, then it works properly. It seems to only break if it runs by itself.

The error is pasted below:

```
Process: com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2, PID: 2942
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2/com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.activity.MovieListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.fragment.MovieDetailFragment.onCreateView(MovieDetailFragment.java:47)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1272)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:600)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Can someone please tell me what i need to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picasso is not throwing a NullPointerException, your code is.

Specifically, the error points to you trying to call `getContext()` on a null object.

In this case, the most likely culprit is `container.getContext()`, meaning your `container` is null.

You didn't provide the code in which you set `container`, but it would appear that when your Activity/Fragment is recreated, you aren't updating that reference.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your reply. I'm aware that my code is wrong. This line is being called from the `onBindView()` method in my recycleradatper. The adapter gets called once the activity is started. That's why I'm at a loss as to why it's happening..

Comment: If `container` is a reference to a view in the Activity that you pass to your Adapter's constructor, the problem is that the `container` refers to a view that no longer exists because the Activity has been recreated, but the Adapter was not.

If this is in your `onBindView()` a more reliable way of getting a context would be to call `holder.itemView.getContext()`.

Comment: That seemed to fix it. Thank you very much!